# Are graphs with certain degree sequences complete?

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$. Let $d_1,d_2,....,d_n$ be the degree sequence of the graph (The degrees are arranged in a descending order, therefore $d_1\geq d_2\geq ...\geq d_n$. Suppose that $d_i+i\geq n$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Does it follow that $G$ is complete ?

Thank you

Comment: $G=\langle V,E\rangle $ is complete iff $\deg(v)=|V|-1$ for each $v\in V$.

Comment: I know. Certainly complete graphs satisfy the property in my question. Can there exist non complete graphs with the property in my question

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is my question clearer now ?

Comment: Ah; it would be clearer if you’d asked whether $d_i+i\ge n$ for $1\le i\le n$ implies that $d_i=n-1$ for $1\le i\le n$, but yes, I do understand now.

Comment: Yes, there can. Arrange the vertices in a pentagon. Connect the two base vertices to each of the others, and connect the two just above them to each other.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. This is basically a question about the possible degree sequences of graphs

Comment: ok. I found a counterexample. I will be back after 2 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Using your own example, the red edges in the picture below show a graph with degree sequence $4,4,3,3,2$.

[image]

Comment: I see. I thought you wanted to draw edges in the place of every side of the pentagon. Thank you

Comment: @Amr: You’re welcome.